# Encapsulate ConcurrentHashMap but still be concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading, akka, concurrenthashmap

For a class project, I'm using the concurrentHashMap to contain a list of active users and their connection details. Multiple threads should be able to get a list of all active users, with 5 threads able to modify the hashMap. When I test it, it seems to work but I don't know if threads are getting blocked and the system is just fast enough.

- I want to encapsulate the concurrentHashMap but I don't know if this would stop its concurrency?
- <strike>I also want there to be only one version of the hashmap so I made the class an enum, terrible and just get  *main* to create it?</strike>
- I don't want other threads to modify the hashMap, so I'm not passing the collection/iterator. Is there a way to pass the collection without remove available?
- *(new)* I called two methods in CoolFeature, one is blocking and other is not. Both can have their places. Are there any issues with theses?

We're using the Akka Actors to create the threads and handle concurrency and my simplified code is below. This is not an assignment question, just part of what I'm creating as part of the project.

EDIT: I changed the code and it'll be good to have a solution that doesn't rely on Akka so others can find the answer useful.

```
package server.management;
public class Sessions {
  static final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Id<User>> sessions = new concurrentHashMap<>();
  private Sessions() { }
}

public class SessionManager {
  public static void create(int connection, Id<User> userId) {
    // checks
    Sessions.sessions.put(connection, userId);
  }

  public static Id<User> getUser(int connection) {
    Id<User> userId = Sessions.sessions.get(connection);
    return userId;
  }

  public static ArrayList<Id<User>> getActiveUsers() {
    ArrayList<Id<User>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Don't pass the sessions.values() directly because the Map can be modified.
    for (Id<User> userId : Sessions.sessions.values()) {
      list.add(userId);
    }
    return list;
  }

  // other methods
}

/* Another thread/akka actor class */
package server;
import server.management.SessionManager;

public class CoolFeature extends AbstractActor {
  ...
  Id<User> client = SessionManager.getUser(1023);
  // do stuff
  CompletableFuture<ArrayList<Id<User>>> futureList =
      CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(SessionManager::getActiveUsers);
  // do stuff
  ArrayList<Id<User>> list = futureList.get();
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With akka actor, you can put a normal Map inside an actor as the state and no need to worry about concurrent access, because with actor model, an actor only processes one message at a time. You can do something like below. The code is in Scala, but you get my idea.

```scala
object Manager {
  case class Get(id: Int)
  case object GetActive
  case class Create(connId: Int, userId: Int)
}

class Manager extends Actor {
  import Manager._
  val sessions = mutable.Map[Int, Int].empty
  override def receive = {
    case Get(id) => sessions.get(id)
    case GetActive => sessions.values
    case Create(connId, userId) => sessions += (connId -> userId)
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: It's also generally a bad idea for code inside an actor (which is what I think OP means when they say "using Akka Actors to create the threads") to manipulate the same state that other actors are manipulating.

Comment: Thanks, creating an actor would be easier. I just thought this actor could get a lot of requests and could be a bottle neck.
@LeviRamsey yeah, the concurrentHashMap locks sections of the map when multiple threads access it. I was hoping this would distribute the load so its not a large bottle neck.

Comment: The CHM's locking will be trustworthy (it's been battle-tested by JVM apps for many years, even if I don't know off the top of my head of formal proofs of correctness).  However, there's nothing preventing an actor from pulling the rug out from another actor. If you're worried about a bottleneck, I would consider implementing the concurrent map with sharded actors (possibly cluster sharded persistent actors, especially if you might want to run across multiple instances for HA etc.)

Comment: @dean As Levi suggested, can do sharded actor e.g. cluster sharding actors if there are a huge amount of requests. Can always start with the simple one-actor solution and test it with the approximate load.